# using Java generic method from Scala

Tags: scala, generics, scala-java-interop

I'm having problem understanding Scalac's error message in this example:

**Bean.java**

```
public class Bean {
  static public class Attribute<T> {
    public final String name;
    public Attribute(String name) {this.name = name;}
    // equals and hashcode omitted for simplicity
  }

  public <T> void set(Attribute<T> attribute, T value) {}

  public static Attribute<Long> AGE = new Attribute<Long>("age");
}
```

**Test.scala**

```
object Test {
  def test() {
    val bean = new Bean();
    bean.set(Bean.AGE, 2L);
  }
}
```

compiling yeilds this (tried with scalac 2.9.2):

```
Test.scala:4: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Bean.Attribute[java.lang.Long]
 required: Bean.Attribute[Any]
Note: java.lang.Long <: Any, but Java-defined class Attribute is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
bean.set(Bean.AGE, 2L);
              ^
one error found
```

why is it requiring Attribute[Any]?
Doing same in Java works fine

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is due to mismatch between `java.lang.Long` and scala `Long`.

`Bean.AGE` is of type `Bean.Attribute[java.lang.Long]`. Hence the scala compiler expects a `java.lang.Long` as the other argument. But you are passing is `2L` which is `scala.Long` and not `java.lang.Long`. Hence it shows error.

Doing this will work as expected:

```
 b.set(Bean.AGE,new java.lang.Long(23))
```

Thanks to @senia, the below is a better alternative:

```
bean.set[java.lang.Long](Bean.AGE, 23)
bean.set(Bean.AGE, 23:java.lang.Long)
```

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley Oops. Yes. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you think `23: java.lang.Long` looks a little bit better? Or even `b.set[java.lang.Long](Bean.AGE, 23)`.

Comment: @senia You are a genius. I have learnt a lot from your answers over past few months here at SO :-)

Comment: thank you, this makes sense although doesn't make me happy. Do you see any way to hide explicit type specification and make this Java API look better for the Scala users?  I'd expect scalac to try Predef.long2Long before failing but it doesn't happen, looks like it tries long2LongConflict instead

Comment: @eprst Well implicits only work for functions with one argument and not more. Had that method been in scala, you could have defined it as: `def set[T](att:Attribute[T])(value:T){}`. And then later ` set(age)(2L)` would have worked. Thanks to currying. But in your case, I do not know of any other better option